# Preg Replace not work for only one input

Tags: php, regex

i'm using preg replace to replace syntax in my output. Here is my code:

```
$input_val_Arr = array("ic"=>'8808295663',
                 "promocodereply"=>'123456',
                 "phone"=>'017123456789');

foreach($input_result as $row)
{
    //eg of $row->input_title is promocodereply, phone, ic  

    $special_key =  $row->input_title;

    $rule = "/<".$row->input_title.">/i";

//if(preg_match('/promocodereply/i', $success_msg))

    if(preg_match($rule, $success_msg))
   {
     if(isset($input_val_Arr[$special_key]))
     {                              
      //$success_msg = preg_replace('/<promocodereply>/i', '123456', $success_msg);

      $success_msg = preg_replace($rule, $input_val_Arr[$special_key], $success_msg);   
    }                       
}
}

var_dump($success_msg);
```

The $success_msg content is `Success! <PROMOCODEREPLY> <PHONE> <IC>`

So the var_dump output should be **Success! 123456 017123456789 8808295663**

However the ic syntax is not replace and this is what i get. `Success! 123456 017123456789 <IC>`

What is the problem here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex is fine. Your `$input_result` array however contains only an entry where `$row->input_title==` is `"IC"` or something. Ths will work with the regex, but fail the `isset($input_val_Arr[$special_key])`. Since that's not a case-insensitive check.

You need to clean up your whole approach. The multiple checks are awfully redundant, and the variable names suck. A single `preg_replace_callback` is advisable for this task, with just `/<(IC|PROMOCODEREPLY|PHONE)>/i` as regex. Or use a single `preg_replace` call with arrays as subject and replacement.

Comment: thanks, after clean up the whole approach, i find that the if else in my code is the culprit and solve the problem.